# How to create a type from string and remove subtring?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an object with keys that end with some sufix and I want to get the `keyof` that object without the sufix.

e.g. where sufix = 'Svg'

```
type FooObj = {
    ASvg: any
    BSvg: any
    CSvg: any
    DSvg: any
}

type KeyofWithoutSufix = WithoutSvgSufix<keyof FooObj> 
// 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D'

type WithoutSvgSufix<T> = ???
```

How could I create the `WithoutSvgSufix` type?
I think it needs some conditional type and string literal but I have no idea how that would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) and [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to strip a fixed suffix off a string literal:

```
type WithoutSvgSufix<T> = T extends `${infer P}Svg` ? P : never
```

This results in the type you wanted:

```
type KeyofWithoutSufix = WithoutSvgSufix<keyof FooObj>
// 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D'
```

You haven't specified what you want to see happen if you pass in something that does not end in the suffix; the above definition just returns `never` for those, so they disappear entirely:

```
type Test = WithoutSvgSufix<"ESvg" | "FSVg" | "GgvS" | "HSvg">
// typo ---------------------------> ~~~~~~   ~~~~~ <-- backwards
// type Test = "E" | "H"
```

If you want to see something else, you should replace `never` with whatever you want.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nA8gIwFZQLxQN4FgBQURUAggMoBuA5gFxQCGAdiAcVAEKW0POvEDCXOkxaFiAESE9RAXwIFQkKAHUAlsAAWcAK7AuZbQDNVADwA8AFQB8mKBagQTwCIwAmAZygADACTZVjIYQAE5QAAoyXF5QAPzhUHSMEBQh8vgK4NAA0hAgcIZqmjp6Rqa2hVq6+qXmANa5+bAIKKhWBAD07VAA5CTdUAA+Pez9Q938oz3i3WmK0BYQ7sDl6pV61AbG5gBEAKJc24NQ2zBkAGpUh0PbAOJUFGRXxwASB234nVCKcFAAtP8AwFA4HAmwAPwhkOIkIhUDM-ygyHoAGNagB3ejBDwdLpzOyLZZYPZPbbPbZAA)

Comment: `never` is perfect, that's exactly what I want. I also realized that if it's a key `Svg` it will return empty string so I added `P extends '' ? never : P` and it's perfect.

Comment: Heh, empty string is what I would expect the right answer should be when you strip `"Svg"` off the end of `"Svg"`.  But you know your use case better than I do.